# Did One Step kill my batch?

Tags: sanitizer

I have been brewing for a while, and have a routine I go through, part of which includes using very hot water (185+) to sanitize my new caps.  On the advice of another brewer, I tried One step on the caps to avoid the slightly metallic taste boiled caps can occasionally impart.  I bottled five gallons of my favorite mocha porter two weeks ago, (without rinsing the caps) and opened one of them last night.  Not only was it flat (very unusual for this recipe) but it had a weird astringent, almost salty flavor.  I tried another bottle from another case, and same thing.  Six bottles later, I have come to the conclusion that not only is it dead, it tastes like crap.  Literally the only change was the sanitizer on the caps.  Anyone have any input?

Comment: This is going to sound "tech support esque;" but, did you remember to put the priming sugar in? I've been in a rush before and thought I had a stuck fermentation because there had been no activity after 2 days...Totally forgot to put the yeast in. As a side note, it does not look like One Step has anything that would degrade into a salt-like off flavor. http://www.ecologiccleansers.com/OneStepDataSheet.pdf

Answer (score 3):

I can't think of any way One Step could have caused that.  I have used it and similar products many times without problems.

Comment: Agreed. Assuming the One-Step wasn't wildly overconcentrated, I don't see how the amount remaining on the cap could do *anything* to the beer.